# How to write "if something -> print" "else if nothing -> print nothing"

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am writing a php function for wordpress that is executed through an XML feed.  Therefore we are excepting a feed and then based on the nodes placing those in our website.  What I need help with is we have a bunch of different images of credentials (i.e BBB, chamber of commerce etc)  What I need therefore is when there is a link to a BBB then it should display a picture, if not then it should be blank.  The problem I am running into is because the BBB links will be random based on different businesses.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

If URL "pic"
else "no pic"

Comment: Can you clarify 1. What kind of data you need to analyze (XML? HTML?) and what you mean by "when there is a link". What does the condition look like? Can you post a real world example?

Comment: I am getting a XML feed [license1] - therefore if [license1] exists then I am going to display a picture.  If [license1] does not exist then nothing will show up.

Example - if [license1] = BBB display picture of BBB logo, else [license1] = nothing display nothing

hope this helps

Comment: Are you asking for a simple if() statement? Your question is either unclear or extraordinarily basic for someone capable of manipulating an XML feed in WordPress.

Comment: Well actually I was given this project without knowing any XML and some php and I am trying to figure it out without any help - so I am forced to use forums and google - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this? Otherwise please explain your problem better.

```
if (!empty($url)) {
    echo '<img src="' .$url. '" />';
}
else {
    echo ' ';
}
```

Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) when `empty` returns false (and therefore `!empty` is `true`) and really consider if this fits your needs.

Comment: Yeah, are we missing something? Is the OP really asking for how to do an if/else structure?

Comment: I think this is what will help me out - I was missing the "!empty" - thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't this do?

```
if($license1) { print "<img src=\"/path/to/bbb.logo\" alt=\"BBB Logo\" />"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A method would be creating an array 
like `$feeds = array("pic","xml");`
then testing if its in array like

```
if in_array($url,$feeds)
// your code;
```

or the second method would be creating an temp var like $`tmp = $url =="pic" ? "pic" : "nopic";`
or to set just an boolean $`tmp = $url =="pic" ? TRUE : FALSE;`

then you can test it like this

```
if($url) // if its == "pic" it would return true otherwise false
 //make your url
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a shorthand way is to do

But when the given var is an array I think you need to use is_array(), or if it's a class objec,t use is_object() to verify that it has content.